# Email is Not Sent using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

its written in the console that the mail is sent but i cant find anything in the inbox.

```
    Sent mail to abo_salah_2010@hotmail.com (5.2ms)
Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 15:53:51 +0200
To: abo_salah_2010@hotmail.com
Message-ID: <53342d6f7e8_12f7c8dfe832535@salah-Dell-System-XPS-L502X.mail>
Subject: Request Accepted by the Carrier
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

NewsletterMailer#weekly

Hi, find me in app/views/app/views/newsletter_mailer/weekly.text.erb

=> #<Mail::Message:32171900, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 15:53:51 +0200>, <To: abo_salah_2010@hotmail.com>, <Message-ID: <53342d6f7e8_12f7c8dfe832535@salah-Dell-System-XPS-L502X.mail>>, <Subject: Request Accepted by the Carrier>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/plain>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
irb(main):002:0>
```

and here is the configuration :

```
    ShipmeProj::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "localhost:3000",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["xxxxx@gmail.com"],
  password: ENV["xxxxx"]
```

Comment: have you configured your email settings?

Comment: Can you provide snippets from your mail server log files? Perhaps the issue isn't in rails at all...

Comment: check your environments file `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` if it is `:test` it will not send email and other setup is poper or not?

Comment: i edited the post please check it again

Comment: @RajarshiDas any other suggestion ?

Comment: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` as it is true and you did not get any error do you use proxy ? test mail server? check those most chnace of network

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a config:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Comment: added it before and still the same problem but i added again now , thanks

Comment: all the rest in your config seems ok (i'm using the same configuration with gmail, i just don't specify the domain as it's localhost), if even with this delivery is not performed, then problem should be elsewhere.

Comment: I even tried to make the domain my IP address but still the same problem.

Comment: yea the domain should not be that important in development environment. the important configs are the perform_deliveries and the delivery_method. Guess problem is somewhere else.